# Its Swiss Cheese! No wait, just circles in a square..... Convexity problem

Tags: geometry

Here is an interesting question.

Consider a square, lets call it $S$.

Now suppose there are $n$ circles in the square where all of the circles are equal and none of them ever intersect.

$S$ does not have a fixed size so if there are $80$ circles, just make a square big enough to fit them. The circles can be any size too as long as they can fit in the square and not touch the border of it.

I have a few questions pertaining to this information.

1. How could one prove that $S$ will be a set of convex polygons if you can cut it s.t. one circle is in each piece?
2. What if we did not have a square but any convex polygon?
3. Would this also work if the radii of the circles are not necessarily equal and are in a convex polygon.
4. What about the three dimensional case?

I apologize for asking quite a few questions. I did not want to create multiple questions since they all go with the given information for the most part. As far as proving this, I am baffled just because I am not sure how to use the given information.

Comment: basically you're asking why there is a always a Voronoi tiling of the square with each piece containing a circle, right?

Comment: Well I do not know what that is so I dont know.

Comment: See [Wikipedia on Voronoi diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) and find the centres of the circles (spheres) and define each polygon (polyhedron) as those points which have the same centre closest.  So the answer will be yes when the circles (or spheres) have equal radii as their centres will be more than $2r$ apart and more than $r$ from the outer square or cube.